# How do I create a new .html webpage onclick?

Tags: javascript, php, html, server, server-side

What I want to do is when the user clicks my html button I want to dynamically create a new webpage on the server. I need the url of the new webpage to have it's own url, that is, it should be different from each other.

In more detail: When the user clicks the button I want to upload a new .html file to the server. So for example if I have a website called www.check.com/index.html when the user clicks the button in the index.html I need to create a new .html that contains some html lines (but no CSS, nothing will be shown on the page). So when the user clicks the button I want a file to be upload to the server with a unique url like www.check/1.html, the second time it'll be check.com/2.html and so on.. I'm fine with it being 1.html, 2.html and so on.

Javascript code:

```
 function makePage(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    alert("webpage " + xmlhttp.responseText + " was successfully created!");
}
var content = "<html><head></head><body><meta name=\"twitter:card\" content=\"summary_large_image\"><meta name=\"twitter:site\" content=\"@nytimes\"><meta name=\"twitter:creator\" content=\"@SarahMaslinNir\"><meta name=\"twitter:title\" content=\"Parade of Fans for Houston’s Funeral\"><meta name=\"twitter:description\" content=\"Blah Blah Blah content.\"><meta name=\"twitter:image\" content=\"\"><script>document.getElementById(\"imgTweet\").innerHTML.write(img);</script></body></html>";
xmlhttp.open("GET","makePage.php?content=" + content,true);
xmlhttp.send();}
```

'img' is a variable in a different page of mine. The webpage gets created by the code is not executed.

Comment: So you need 3 things. (1) An HTML button and JS code to hit a PHP script via AJAX. (2) A PHP script which gets an autoincremented number from the DB, creates and HTML file and saves it using the autoincremented number. (3) A database with one table, and one autoincremented ID field.

Comment: Are you using a framework? .. This allows creating pages based on url variables. it seems like you will need to start there. Laraval seems to be popular, but better yet go find a video tutorial on MVC framework to build your own simplistic version so you learn some basics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp) to execute php. Creating new file in php is really simple with [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

here is an example:
makePage.html:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <button onclick="makePage()">click</button>
    <script src="makePage.js">
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

makePage.php:

```
<?php
$content = $_GET["content"];
$file = uniqid() . ".html";
file_put_contents($file, $content);
echo $file;
?>
```

makePage.js

```
function makePage(){
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        alert("webpage " + xmlhttp.responseText + " was successfully created!");
    }
    var content = "<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\" /> </head><body>new website<script>alert(\"test\")</script></body></html>";
    xmlhttp.open("GET","makePage.php?content=" + content,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

hope this will help

Comment: Thank you! Could you please add the AJAX script?

Comment: AJAX script is included in "makePage.html"

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll try your method. I've added a bit to the question.

Comment: It works exactly as you want just remove "path/" from .php file and edit "content" variable in .html to text you want to have in new page. And php uniqid() will provide you unique name unless make two pages at exact same time.

Comment: Fabulous, thanks. I'll try it out and get back to you in the coming day.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! How is this working, where are the files being saved and stored?

Comment: By editing "$file" in .php you can set where files will be stored, if you remove "path/" files will be stored in same folder as .php file. You can find more about file_put_contents() on the internet.

Comment: When I add some meta tags and <script></script> and stuff to the content variable it stops working. Why is that?

Comment: Yeah i tried it, the problem is </script>, you can solve it by moving the whole script from .html page to .js file.

Comment: I can update the answer if you want

Comment: Yes please, thanks again!

Comment: When I add the alert or any script it still doesn't work..

Comment: That's strange because it works for me

Comment: It's not working for me when I remove the \ from the alert.

Comment: \ should be there because it allows you to have nested quotes (\"). If you don't like it replace \" with '

Comment: Ohh, okay. Thank you!

Comment: When I add the (\") my html code doesn't work in the new file. How do fix this?

Comment: That is, the code doesn't execute in the new .html file.

Comment: Write your code here

Comment: Done. Don't worry about the content. When I run the code it gets put in my new .html page perfectly but the code [even if I add a simple alert(\"something\"); ] it doesn't run.

Comment: `document.getElementById("imgTweet").innerHTML.write(img);` this is the problem, it gives this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: so there is problem in javascript in new created page not in my scripts