# Build a reporting history on my google web app

Tags: web, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like some advise how I should do.

Context: 
I have a web app that I build with Google Apps Script. My web app takes 16 sheets of my spreadsheet and display on an HTML page.

My goal now, is to build a history of that reporting  (each time we click on a button for instance, its save reports in a new link).

I thought about two options:

First: Save html content -> create a new html page and insert the html content. ( then loop to the repository to get link).

Second: Save  spreadsheet each time (but I am not sure how to dynamically get the id of the new spreadsheet).

Any advice?

Edit 
Code.gs //to get spreadSheet data.

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1klU634iH2nHNMiFeLxAL39KfV8pwoGtstEkWS21gK48/edit#gid=785104696";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var cps = ss.getSheetByName("Cockpit 2019").getRange(9,1,27,10).getValues();
...
...
var sts = ss.getSheetByName("TCD - STEAM");
var datas= [wls, bss, bis, mwds,hds ,bfas,ess, its, rs, itses, secus, ddfs, d2sis, dmcs, gclouds, sts];

function doGet(e) {
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");




  return tmp.evaluate(); 
}

function include(File) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(File).getContent();
};

function getSheetDetails(datas) {
  var rows = datas.getLastRow();
  var cols = datas.getLastColumn();
  return datas.getRange(1,1,rows, cols).getValues();
}

function getallDatas() {
  var allSheets = []
  for(var i = 0; i< datas.length; i++){
     var temp = 0;
    temp = getSheetDetails(datas[i]);
    allSheets.push(temp);
  }
return allSheets
}
```

Page-js // display my tables with javascript

```
 function genereTable(data) {
        for (var index = 0; index<data.length; index++){
              for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                  var row = document.createElement("tr");
                  for(j = 0; j<data[index][i].length; j++) {
                      var col = document.createElement("th");
                      col.textContent = data[index][i][j];
                      row.appendChild(col);
               }
                  arrayHead[index].appendChild(row);
            }

            for (i = 1; i< data[index].length; i++) {
                var rowb = document.createElement("tr");
                for (j = 0; j < data[index][i].length; j++) {
                    var colb = document.createElement("td");
                    colb.textContent = data[index][i][j];
                    rowb.appendChild(colb);
            }
            arrayBody[index].appendChild(rowb);
        }
    }         
}
```

html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
      <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <?!= include("page-css"); ?>

  </head>
  <body>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper" id="navbar">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#mwd" target="test" onclick="document.getElementById('mwd').scrollIntoView();">mwd</a></li>
        <li><a href="#bis">Cockpipt</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Gagné/Perdu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <h1> Reporting</h1>
  <section>
    <h2> Cockpit </h2>
    <div id="cps">
       <table class="striped">
         <thead id="table-cps-head">
         </thead>
        <tbody id="table-cps">
        </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
  </section>
....
15 more tables
```

EDIT: I success
With the help of ziganotschka, i made a button to save my spreadsheet in an drive directory

```
function createSsheet(date) {
  var dest = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxx");
  DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("xxxx").getId()).makeCopy("Report: " + date, dest);
  return true ;
}
```

in my Html page for the link :

```
 <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
  <? for(var i =0; i<list.length; i++) {?>
  <li><a href="#" onClick="getHistory(<?=list[i]?>)" target="_self"><?= listNames[i] ?></a> </li>
  <?} ?>
```

on my JS i pass the old Spreadsheet on my params

```
function getHistory(params) {
   document.getElementById("table-cps-head").innerHTML ="";
   document.getElementById("table-cps").innerHTML= "";
   for (var i = 0; i<arrayHead.length; i++) {
       arrayHead[i].innerHTML ="";
    }
   for (var i = 0; i<arrayBody.length; i++) {
       arrayBody[i].innerHTML ="";
    }

    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(cockpitTab).withFailureHandler(oops).getCockpit(params);
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(genereTable).withFailureHandler(oops).getallDatas(params);

}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code from your current Web App? This will make it easier to understand how your code should be modified to implement the history of reporting. Also, I do not fully understand your statement about the new spreadsheet id - do you want to save the spreadsheet after each edit as a new spreadsheet (with a new ID)?

Comment: i add some code. for the new spreadsheat, wha i ment to mean. If i create new spreadsheet, this would have a new id.  One think, (dont want to make a post for that), do you know how to scroll to view with google app? those iframe open me a new page with the "a href="#mwd" .... <div id="mwd"..> strange behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can do the following:

- Implement a button that will run with `google.script.run` a function an Apps Script function that reads the current version of your spreadsheet
- Pass the spreadsheet `data` with [`withSuccessHandler`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) into a JS function
- Create dynamically a new button linked to a dynamically created new HTML page
- Embed `data` into the new html page
  +Every time you click on the `Add new Spreadsheet` button, a new website with the current version of the spreadsheet `data` will be created - with enables you to track the `data` history
- The following code illustrates how you can dynamically read data with Apps Script and pass it back into the `html` file where it can be used to dynamically create websites and buttons - please adapt it to your needs

```
var url = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var cps = ss.getSheetByName("Cockpit 2019");
var sts = ss.getSheetByName("TCD - STEAM");
var datas= [cps, sts];

function doGet(e) {
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
  return tmp.evaluate(); 
}

function getSheetDetails(datas) {
  var rows = datas.getLastRow();
  var cols = datas.getLastColumn();
  return datas.getRange(1,1,rows, cols).getValues();
}

function getallDatas() {
  var allSheets = []
  for(var i = 0; i< datas.length; i++){
     var temp = 0;
    temp = getSheetDetails(datas[i]);
    allSheets.push(temp);
  }
return allSheets
}
```

```
 <body>
  <input type="button" onClick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(addButton)
          .getallDatas()"  value="Add new Spreadsheet">
  <script>      
function genereTable(data) {
       ...
}

function addButton(data) {
  var d = new Date();
  var newButton = document.createElement("input");
  newButton.type = "button";
  newButton.value = "This is the new report created on "+d; 
  newButton.name = "Button "+d; 
  newButton.onclick = function makePage(body) { 
  genereTable(data);
 // more information how to implement a new makePage() function here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379444/how-do-i-create-a-new-html-webpage-onclick
  };
    document.body.appendChild(newButton); 
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: So, do you think its the best way to do what i meant to do? copy the spreadsheet, create a new html page and add the link in a dropdown list?

Comment: I believe you did not provide your full code (e.g. I cannot see how and when the different Apps Script functions are called), so it is hard for me to understand the full scope of your project, but if you want to create a new Spreadsheet on button click and store your reports in the new spreadsheet instead of the old one - you can do it as explained above. You do not need to create a new html page, you just create a new spreadsheet (and thus a new file ID and URL) on every button click.

Comment: I believe i do need create html page to display the new copie that i create on my web app.

Comment: Is the URL of your web deployment not your html page already? You can dynamically (with triggers like onSubmit or onClick) run JS (and inside them Apps Script) functions which would add new menu entries and links to your webpage.

Comment: Thank you very mutch for your help, but i may have not made myself clear.  I have link part of my code (not all, because is redundant). What i want to achieve, is, dynamically, in my html page, display all the spreadsheet  saved every week. To do so, like you suggest i can create a copy of the spreadsheet via a button, (i can manage this) but i struggle to know how to  display the copy and add a link in my html page

Comment: I updated my answer to give you a more detailed example

Comment: i success, thx for your support, i edited my question to show i did.