# Selector Change based on previous selectors with dynamic lists

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to generate a selector that populates with various tasks based on a previous selector. I have seen the short way to do it with if/else if block code, however for each of my selections I have 20+ options that could be chosen.

I have tried to put options on various sheets within the spread sheet and run a if/else if statement so the drop down will populate with tasks that are from one of the sheets associated with a selection option.

```
<!--my selection i want to base the next selection options off of-->
<select id = 'reason'>
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose Reason</option>
<option value = 'prec'>PREC</option>
<option value = 'crh'>CRH</option>
<option value = 'bh'>BH</option>
<option value = 'ih'>IH</option>
<option value = 'rh'>RH</option>

</select>
<Label>Call Reason</Label>
</div>

<!-- function that generates tasks dynamically from a sheet -->
function getTasks(){

  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName('PREC');
  var list = ws.getRange(1,1).getDataRegion().getValues();
  var options = {};
  list.forEach(function(v){
    options[v[0]]= null;
  });

<!--essentially If someone chose "CRH" I would want it to open the sheet 
with the CRH options -->

The way I wrote the loop didn't work.

function getTasks(){

  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var options = {};
//basically added else ifs for each reason with the same code just dif 
//sheet names
  if (document.getElementById('reason')='prec'){
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName('PREC');
  var list = ws.getRange(1,1).getDataRegion().getValues();

  list.forEach(function(v){
    options[v[0]]= null;
}
  });
return options
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Google Web App is in general composed of:

- Apps Script code in the `.gs`file
- HTML code in the `html`file
- JavaScript code within the `<script></script>` tags

### The interaction between those components:

- In the `.gs` file a [`doGet()`function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) must be implemented to create an [HTML output](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createHtmlOutputFromFile(String))
- A JS function can be called from the `html`code, e.g. `<select id = 'reason' onchange="getSheet()">`
- An Apps Script function can be called from JS within the `<script></script>` part (alternatively within the  [`<?...?>` scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)) with [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction), parameters can be passed to this function from the `html` file
- A return value of a called Apps Script function can be passed back to JS with the [`withSuccessHandler`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service#createHtmlOutputFromFile(String))

### For your case:

- The chosen dropdown option can accessed with JS (not with Apps Script!) part

```
var dropdown=document.getElementById('reason');
var sheet=dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

- The chosen sheet name needs to be passed to an Apps Script function where SpreadsheetApp methods are accessible
- The options returned by the Apps Script function can be returned back to JS and implemented into the `html` framework

> Here is how you can do it:

`.gs` file:

```
function doGet() {  
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
}

function getTasks(sheet){
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName(sheet);
  var list = ws.getRange(1,1).getDataRegion().getValues(); 
  var options = {};
  list.forEach(function(v){
    options[v[0]]= null;
  });
  return options;
}
```

`html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
    <!--my selection i want to base the next selection options off of-->
<select id = 'reason' onchange="getSheet()">
<option value="" disabled selected>Choose Reason</option>
<option value = 'prec'>PREC</option>
<option value = 'crh'>CRH</option>
<option value = 'bh'>BH</option>
<option value = 'ih'>IH</option>
<option value = 'rh'>RH</option>
</select>
<Label>Call Reason</Label>
</div>
<script>
function getSheet(){
var dropdown=document.getElementById('reason');
var sheet=dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
console.log(sheet);
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getTasks(sheet);
  }
function onSuccess(options) {        
        //do something
      }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you know how this would change if I wanted to do a dynamic multiple select? still changing options based on the sheet just into a list form instead of autocomplete

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box You can loop through all options  and perform google.script.run within the if statement - it will run for each selected sheet. Not sure what you mean by "a list form instead of autocomplete", I do not know what exactly you want to do with your sheet data and list. Check here how to dynamically create a button and html page - maybe this is what you mean:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57310460/build-a-reporting-history-on-my-google-web-app/57326975#57326975

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean - why not use "onchange"?

```
<div>
    <select id = 'reason1' onchange="MyFunction(0)">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Reason</option>
    <option value = 'prec'>PREC</option>
    <option value = 'crh'>CRH</option>
    <option value = 'bh'>BH</option>
    <option value = 'ih'>IH</option>
    <option value = 'rh'>RH</option>

    </select>
    <Label>Call Reason</Label>
    </div>
<div>

<div>
    <select id = 'reason2' onchange="MyFunction(1)"><!--select[1]-->
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Reason</option><!--opt[0]-->
    <option value = 'prec2'>PREC</option><!--opt[1]-->
    <option value = 'crh2'>CRH</option><!--opt[2]-->
    <option value = 'bh2'>BH</option><!--opt[3]-->
    <option value = 'ih2'>IH</option><!--opt[4]-->
    <option value = 'rh2'>RH</option><!--opt[5]-->

    </select>
    <Label>Call Reason</Label>
    </div>
<div>

<div>
    <select id = 'reason3' onchange="MyFunction(2)"><!--select[3]-->
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Reason</option>
    <option value = 'prec3'>PREC</option>
    <option value = 'crh3'>CRH</option>
    <option value = 'bh3'>BH</option>
    </select>
    <Label>Call Reason</Label>
    </div>
<div>


<script>
function MyFunction(x) {
    //x - position of select in the array
    var selects = [document.getElementById('reason1'), document.getElementById('reason2'), document.getElementById('reason3')]; //store all your selects in an array to easily get them
    var url = 'your url here'; 
    var selectedOption = selects[x].selectedIndex; //index of selected option
    var selectedSelectId = event.target.id; //id of select changed
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var wsName = selectedSelectId + '-' + selectedOption;
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName(wsName); //now you should name each of your spreedsheed "id of the select - option index", for example "reason1-1" for "prec", "reason3-2" for "crh3" etc;
    //rest of your code here
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think that's what I am looking for.
if reason = prec then these options display if crh a different list 
<option value = '1'>Doesn't like box</option>
<option value = '2'>Uses other service</option>
<option value = '3'>filled locally</option>
<option value = '4'>off product</option>
<option value = '5'>doesnt like shipping</option>
ecetera
</select>

the problem is I have 20 for prec, 10 for crh, 7 for the others and they're all different

Comment: @Samuel Daly, I've edited my answer, will it help you now?

Comment: no, I am using materialize selectors and while it's initialized and the function is working and printing the right selections in the console, the id that is shown on the console is not the same id targeted in html

Comment: I don't even know if that makes sense because I have never seen it or had it happen to me before

Comment: <!-- id shown on console when i inspect-->
     <ul id="select-options-40e806c5-c1ce-45d1-f1f3-eceef8282fc7" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown" tabindex="0" 
     style="display: block; width: 574.688px; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 0px; transform-origin: 0px 0px; opacity: 1; transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);"></ul>


     <!-- id still in console but under the block above in the console, populated with the appropriate values -->
     <select id="og" tabindex="-1">

Comment: I've never worked with materialize, I think this question will help you more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28258106/materialize-css-select-doesnt-seem-to-render